# Using aggregate value in condition in SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm creating a `SELECT` statement between two tables with a one-to-many relationship and I want to use the aggregate value in the condition where I want to get a list of records with more than one related records in table B.

The following `SELECT` statement gives me the number of related records in `table2` but I only want those records in my result where there are more than one related records in `table2`. In other words, in the following code, I want the `NumberOfRelatedRecords` to be greater than 1.

How do I use that in my `WHERE` condition?

```
select a.Id, count(b.Id) as NumberOfRelatedRecords
from table1 as a
   inner join table2 as b on a.Id = b.RelatedId
group by a.Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using HAVING

```
select a.Id, count(b.Id) as NumberOfRelatedRecords
from table1 as a
   inner join table2 as b on a.Id = b.RelatedId
group by a.Id
HAVING Count(b.ID) > 1
```

Comment: Glad it worked. When you are able, please mark as answer so others can find this if they have the same question.

Comment: Will do! For some reason SO doesn't let me mark it as the answer right away.Thanks again.